# Automated emails from Woocommerce marked as spam. Wrong Return path

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, spam

All the automated emails sent from woocommerce from [my website](https://www.racebooking.net/foto-franciacorta/) are marked as spam. Here is the header:

```
Delivered-To: fontanavideostudios@gmail.com
Received: by 10.64.118.34 with SMTP id kj2csp1351282ieb;
        Thu, 2 Apr 2015 05:19:26 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.194.176.4 with SMTP id ce4mr94751409wjc.75.1427977166190;
        Thu, 02 Apr 2015 05:19:26 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <racebook>
Received: from ns362512.ip-91-121-174.eu ([2001:41d0:1:ef28::1])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id e5si8490541wjw.70.2015.04.02.05.19.25
        for <fontanavideostudios@gmail.com>;
        Thu, 02 Apr 2015 05:19:26 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: temperror (google.com: error in processing during lookup of racebook: DNS timeout) client-ip=2001:41d0:1:ef28::1;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=temperror (google.com: error in processing during lookup of racebook: DNS timeout) smtp.mail=racebook;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@
Received: by ns362512.ip-91-121-174.eu (Postfix, from userid 504)
    id EA9BA1608B; Thu,  2 Apr 2015 14:16:42 +0200 (CEST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=racebooking.net;
    s=default; t=1427977002;
    bh=8Bpk5qKGS/snauZWTEWdgTP8RA8IIyUciiaTtpnN268=;
    h=To:Subject:Date:From;
    b=uPVvgt52HbS6VIzCMagUSpBDCvF787qIleF13Yw/7E95kuXdVJSdCo5IjbUTmGuBm
     TUSe7jiDf4RfGzq2BQJUnFd91RljAVJHxWscY9U/ZFqGU65MjeIIfN7jLa+/k6Aj0/
     m2bULvyRjwdU1EInjtl9y3SC593kACANJPR+u8/Y=
To: fontanavideostudios@gmail.com
Subject: Puoi scaricare i files accedendo a questa pagina: https://www.racebooking.net/foto-franciacorta/mio-account/
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 504:class-phpmailer.php
Date: Thu, 2 Apr 2015 12:16:42 +0000
From: Foto Franciacorta <noreply@racebooking.net>
Message-ID: <ddc1208f249c3ad34b96dad0437c49d8@www.racebooking.net>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

The cause is probably that the Return-Path is wrong. Instead of `noreply@racebooking.net` (correct) it is `racebook`, (incorrect). How can i fix it? I couldn't find any setting into Woocommerce options to fix the Return Path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that by using [this plugin](https://abdussamad.com/archives/567-Fixing-the-WordPress-Email-Return-Path-Header.html) which simply copies the "from" email into the Return Path